# How to learn and memorize animals classification to get an intuition about them?

Tags: zoology, classification

I would like to have a good intuition on how close is what animal to which one and how large each group is by number of species and population. I was wondering if there is a good website with good demographics and graphs that could help me memorize it because it's really so hard to make up the tree myself from wikipedia pages!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very good website and application for that. It's called [Onezoom tree of life explorer](http://www.onezoom.org/) which I believe is for London imperial collage.

Comment: OneZoom won't be of much help for sometimes to get a broad vision of the most considered branches of the tree of life. It is too detail for such purpose.

Comment: I'm not choosing this answer so as to gain more attention in hope of getting some better alternatives. If I don't get anything better in a few days I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is the Tree of Life web project, which includes species richness information in the lower levels of the tree and allows reasonably easy navigation of subtrees. You can find the animal portal [here](http://tolweb.org/Animals).

EDIT -- another alternative, which is in active development, is this integration of Wikipedia and the Open Tree of Life [Hyperbolic Tree](https://glouwa.github.io/).

Comment: It is very good! but the problem is that it is very slow! with onezoom it's like a map but with this you have to load the page again each time you navigate which becomes frustrating.

Comment: @ladybug you may find that [open Tree of Life](https://ot14.opentreeoflife.org/opentree/argus/opentree9.1@ott93302) has a smoother browsing interface. Not sure about number of taxa, though.